# find a random entry from an association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Controller:

```
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @galleries = Gallery.all
  end
end
```

View:

```
<% for gallery in @galleries %>
  <%= image_tag(gallery.image.url(:medium)) %>
<% end %>
```

I have 2 models, Photo which belongs to Gallery,which has many Photos.
I want to display an image (preferably random rather than :first) from each gallery on the gallery index page.
I know the code I have is wrong as I haven't described which image to select from the gallery, but I'm not sure how to do this... I thought that using `@photos = @galleries.photos.find(:first)` would work but I get an undefined method 'photos' in the controller.

Comment: thanks for all the answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in Rails 2 + MySQL

```
class Photos < ActiveRecord::Base
  # for MySQL:
  named_scope :random, lambda { |n| {:order => "RAND()", :limit => n || 1 }}
  # for SQLite and PostgreSQL
  named_scope :random, lambda { |n| {:order => "RANDOM()", :limit => n || 1 }}
end
```

Then you can do something like

```
gallery.photos.random[0]
```

`gallery.photos.random` will return 1 Photo randomly, but it will still return an array, that's why you need the `[0]` to get the first element of this array. you can also do `gallery.photos.random.first`.

If you want more than one random image you can call `gallery.photos.random(10)` to get 10 random photos.

Answer (score 0):

@galleries is an array so you can't write `@galleries.photos.find(:first)` but you have to write 
`@galleries[0].photos.find(:first)`

for random order try following

```
<% for gallery in @galleries %>

<%= image_tag(gallery.photos.order('rand()')) %>
```

Comment: `gallery.photos.order('rand()')` will return an array, which can't be used by image_tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the @galleries array for its photos which will not work. You need to ask an instance of Gallery for its photos.

So within your for loop then the following should work for you

```
<% for gallery in @galleries %>
<%= image_tag(gallery.photos.first.image.url(:medium)) %>
```

If you want to get one photo in Random order then you could adpot Salils suggestion or perhaps add a method to the Gallery model as follows :-

```
def random_image()
  photos.all[rand(photos.all.size)]
end
```

And then within your foreach loop just do `<%= image_tag(gallery.random_image) %>`

Comment: `photos.all[rand(photos.all.size)]` this is not a good idea, you shouldn't load all photos from the DB if you only want one

Comment: @Jens F. I agree with you, but in the absence of any information on which  database he was using I didn't want to propose a database specific solution. This will work for all DBs.